# Incremental project saving in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, web, project, save

Usually when I start a web site project and build on it over time, every time I want to save my project, I save it and keep a copy of that saving that consisted of all project files in a .rar file and keep a lot of Incremented saving .rar files , I do it because I could possibly mess things up and sometimes I run out of idea what went wrong, so that previous version of my web site project will help me have a return point to where things were OK.

I'm not sure if it's the best approach for this purpose, I was wondering if there is any tools or extensions to make it easier, so every time I save my project that extension or something do it for me, or is it any better approach to do this that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best approach is [version control](http://betterexplained.com/articles/a-visual-guide-to-version-control/). Look at [svn](http://subversion.tigris.org/) or [git](http://git-scm.com/) for instance, there are also VS extensions so you can use them from within the IDE if that is what you are after.

Comment: Thanks, after reviewing some post and comparison between SVN and Git I've chosen SVN system and AnkhSvn with TortoiseSVN for creating local repository, but the discussions on this topic and comparisons was a little confusing, I've chosen AnkhSvn because it was easier to setup and use, also I use it on local machine, am I missing something or is there a better alternative for newbies?

Comment: You'll be fine. When you're just starting to learn this it does not really matter which tools you use. Stick with what you have now, read and experiment to gain enough insight, then start looking around for other tools that might suite you better (or might not).